# XIB file not loading from framework

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have created cocoa touch framework where I have created `UIViewController` class which has the ui in `xib` file. I have done required binding between xib and controller files like file owner connecting to controller class.

I have created another xib and controller files in separate project as normal ios app. There I tried to present this ViewController it was coming on to the screen but when I tried to load the controller present in framework only black screen was coming up to screen.

I have added `xib` files in `copy bundle resources` part of `build phases` in xcode. But when I pod install the framework locally I am able to see only controller file along with other `swift` files but not the `xib` ones.

```
let oPController  = OPController()

let oNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: oPController)
controller.present(oNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is there any special care to be taken when framework contains `xib` files?

**Note** When I look in the installed pods in project I cannot see any xib files there.

Comment: You have to specify the `Bundle` to load xib from. When you use `init` without parameters, it will use `Bundle.main` which is not the correct one in this case. Of course, the framework bundle has to be copied correctly during the build.

Comment: where I have to do this?

Comment: Is it ok to have xib files in `copy bundle resources` ?

Comment: You should try `OPController(nibName: nil, bundle: Bundle(for: OPController.self)` first. That should make sure the xib is loaded from the correct bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the podspec file

```
  s.source_files = "ReusableViewController/*.{swift,h,m,xib,storyboard}"
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MyFramework' => ['Pod/Classes/**/*.{storyboard,xib,xcassets,json,imageset,png}']
  }
  s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"
  s.swift_version = "4.0"
```

Check this link to load your xib file from framework

**https://github.com/Ajithram007/reusableVC**

```
let nibName: String = "SignInView"
var view: UIView!

public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}
public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    self.view = UINib(nibName: self.nibName, bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    self.view.frame = bounds
    self.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating any ViewControllers using xib's in your framework.
You must do these things.

1. Make sure you have added `xib` as resources in podspec file in case of cocoapod library.
2. As per Sulthan's answer and which I tested, When any `UIViewController` class is loaded dynamically using xib and this class is present in some framework then you have to explicitly give the context of bundle while dynamically loading the class

Call like this

```
let oPController = OPController(nibName: "OPController", bundle:
    Bundle(for:OPController.self))
```

where this class looks like

```
class OPController : UIViewController {
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```